# Maven doesn't resolve hibernate-c3p0's dependency on slf4j

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0, slf4j

When I include `hibernate-c3p0` in my Maven's `pom.xml` file, I get a runtime `NoClassDefFoundError` as it can't find `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`. It was my impression that Maven would resolve this dependency – so if c3p0 requires slf4j, then slf4j would be downloaded and included.

My `pom.xml` file has:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

It could be that slf4j is an optional dependency. You can check the transitive dependencies very easily using the dependency plugin

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

will show you a tree listing of exactly what depends on what. If slf4j is not a dep, you can add it explicity.

HTH

Answer (score 4):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` for `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` indicates that no SLF4J binding could be found. By transitivity, hibernate-c3p0 depends on slf4j-api. However, slf4j-api cannot function without a binding. See SLF4J user manual for details: [www.slf4j.org/manual.html](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)

You just need to add one of slf4j-simple, slf4j-log4j12, slf4j-jdk14, or logback-classic as a dependency. The SLF4J manual page mentioned earlier should have the details.

Comment: or the famous slf4j-nop, it's pretty fast :)